# Running `go test` in parent directory of multiple go modules

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

Take a look at this directory structure:

```
/root
    /one
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        main_test.go
    /two
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        main_test.go
```

Let's say I'm in the parent directory `root/` and I want to run all the tests in all subdirectories. What do I do? I've tried `go test./...` and got the following error:

```
go: warning: "./..." matched no packages
no packages to test
```

Comment: `find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this will not work with `go test`, which expects to work on a single module rooted in the current directory or its parent. It won't work with nested modules either.

You'll need a shell trick like using `find` or something equivalent to execute in each module (see Cerise Limón's comment for example). Projects will typically use a `Makefile` or a `test.sh` script to run that.

---

One [larger project I was working on](https://github.com/google/go-cloud) has a list of all its modules (https://github.com/google/go-cloud/blob/master/allmodules) and then several scripts that operate on this list. For example the [test script](https://github.com/google/go-cloud/blob/master/internal/testing/runchecks.sh) just [loops through](https://github.com/google/go-cloud/blob/master/internal/testing/runchecks.sh#L90) this file and runs `go test` for each directory, along other things.

You don't necessarily need a separate file listing the modules (the `go-cloud` project uses that for other management tasks) but it just demonstrates one way large projects with multiple modules handle things.

Comment: So then what is the point of "./..." if it won't work with sub-packages?

Comment: Also, `go test root/one` produces `main module (root) does not contain package root/one` (even if `one/go.mod` specifies that package name.)

Comment: @JeffLearman the point of `go test ./...` is to run all tests on sub packages, not on submodules.

In 99.9% of the cases what you want are actually sub packages, not submodules so `go test` actually covers the most common use-case very well.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting [@Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%c3%b3n)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163306/running-go-test-in-parent-directory-of-multiple-go-modules#comment108202519_61163306) to answer:

```
find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \;
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it always returns a 0 exit code, which is not desirable in CI. I'm trying to figure out a way to make it exit with nonzero if one of the tests fails. I will report back if I figure it out

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337961/62907

Answer (score 0):

Building on other answers here:

```bash
find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \;
```

works but always returns a 0 exit code. I need this to fail my CI if any test fails.

```bash
find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \; | grep -zqv FAIL
```

works for me (note by default grep returns status code 0 if there is a match)