# How to run tests in a multimodule Go project

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-modules

I'm learning Go with the specialization [Programming with Google Go](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/google-golang). It has several courses, each of which has several modules.

My project looks like the following (made with https://ascii-tree-generator.com/):

```
google-golang/
├─ .github/
│  ├─ workflows/
│  │  ├─ ci.yml
├─ golang-getting-started/
│  ├─ module1/
│  │  ├─ main.go
│  │  ├─ main_test.go
│  ├─ module2/
│  │  ├─ trunc/
│  │  │  ├─ main.go
│  │  │  ├─ main_test.go
├─ .gitignore
├─ README.md
```

**I'd like to run all the tests in the `*_test.go` files for every commit**, and it's not clear to me how to do that from the root directory (`google-golang`). I don't see a need for one module to import another as the exercises can be done independently. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55041915/839733) has two answers, one suggests using submodules, another recommends using Go workspace, but neither provide specific instructions that someone new like me can learn from.

I'm not asking for help on GitHub Actions, I know how to write those. I'm looking for one or more commands that'll find and run the tests.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163306/running-go-test-in-parent-directory-of-multiple-go-modules . By the way, the output of your `tree` does not show the presence of `go.mod` files in each submodule.

Comment: @blackgreen There aren't any `go.mod` files, so the output is correct.

Comment: Yes, what I want to say is that you are supposed to have `go.mod` files in there

Comment: If there is no go.mod file you are not using modules making the question about how to run test for all modules nonsensical. Please read (and follow word for word) the "Getting Started" section of https://go.dev/doc/.

Comment: Why? I don't have any need to import a module from another. @jiang's answer seems to be correct, putting a `go.mod` file in the root dir is enough to find the tests.

Comment: your question is about a multi-module project

Comment: If you have a go.mod file you are using modules. With one go.mod you have one module. You probably mix up "module" and "package". Please consult the official documentation for this type of fundamentals.

Comment: @Volker Did you see my comment above? I've a project, structure shown above, and I asked a specific question. I can care less about pedagogical Go discussions that don't help run the tests. If there is needed a `go.mod` file in the root or somewhere else, feel free to say so in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem confused about what a module is. The rule of thumb is, one `go.mod` file equals one module. [Go Wiki, gomod](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod):

> A module is defined by a tree of Go source files with a go.mod file in the tree's root directory.

Based on your directory tree shown in your question, there is no `go.mod` file in sight, hence nothing there is a Go module. As a matter of fact, if you attempt running a module-aware command from `google-golang` or `golang-getting-started` you'll have:

> go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'

If you want to run all tests from the root of a **multi-module** repo, as the title of your question says, with Go 1.17 you can:

1. init the sub-modules:

```
$ cd google-golang/golang-getting-started/module1
$ go mod init example.com/module1
$ cd ../module2
$ go mod init example.com/module2
```

2. use [the trick suggested by Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163306/running-go-test-in-parent-directory-of-multiple-go-modules) from the root dir of the multi-module project

```
$ cd google-golang
$ find . -name go.mod -execdir go test ./... \;
```

---

If you don't actually care about keeping the sub-repos as separate modules, you can init a module in the root repo and run all tests from there:

```
$ cd google-golang # or google-golang/golang-getting-started/
$ go mod init example.com/mainmod
$ go test ./...
```

...however, even this hack works right now, it doesn't make a lot of sense, because your repos named `moduleN` have `main.go` files, whose packages are supposedly named `main`, in each of them. So they are indeed organized as separate sub-modules.