# run go test command on multiple testfiles with go.work file

Tags: go, go-work

As of go 1.18 it is possible to use "go.work" files as multimodule workspace save file, equivalent to a "go.mod" file.

I want to know how to use the defined "go.work" file in the command go test.

I tried multiple approaches. When I print the go.work env variables everything seems to work.

How do I use the "go test" command on a "go.work" file?

lets assume i have a directory with two subdirectories with each a go.mod file and two .go source files (file.go and file_test.go) and the main directory with just the go.work file.

`go test -v .\go.work` --> not possible

`go test  ".\ ..."`  --> doesn't work as specified, it can't resolve it correctly.

The flag `build.experimentalWorkspaceModule` is set to false because it isn't needed anymore. Just `go test all` seems to work, but I just want to test my packages, not the whole packages installed.

I dug into the whole documentation, I cant find an example because it seems to be new and not used frequently, the pkg.go.dev doesn't supply info.

Also not here https://go.googlesource.com/tools/+/refs/heads/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `go.work` can be used to this end. Workspaces is a part of the modules system, and are basically used to make it easier (for you) to set up a **local** multi-module repository. The following quote is from the [proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md#files):

> The go.work file specifies a set of **local modules** that comprise a workspace. When invoked in workspace mode, the go command will always select these modules and a consistent set of dependencies.

And this one from the workspace tutorial:

> `go.work` can be used instead of adding `replace` directives to work across multiple modules.

And finally this one from the [official docs](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces):

> A workspace is a collection of modules **on disk** that are used as the main modules when running minimal version selection (MVS).

Running the test suite of several modules at once is orthogonal to go.work's use case. For that, you still have to use a shell script (see [Running `go test` in parent directory of multiple go modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163306/running-go-test-in-parent-directory-of-multiple-go-modules)) or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response , in my opinion it should be part of the normal behaviour because you already point to a direcotry each and also have a accordingly go.mod file and files with _test to put it in a queue.

Comment: @DataPhaseDan Yeah maybe, however the genesis of the workspaces feature lies in *multi-module* management, hence its primary use case is to simplify many `replace` directives across modules on the same local system, whereas `go test` operates on a single main module. Perhaps try proposing that on the issue tracker, but I feel it's simply outside the scope of go.work